# Post for with header (according to CURL sample)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, curl

I need to post a form with a header, the CURL of that is

```
curl -X POST "URL" -H "accept: application/json" -H "token: TOKEN VALUE" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"amount\": 1000, \"expireInSeconds\": 0, \"factorNumber\": \"string\", \"redirectUrl\": \"string\"}"
```

I did it like below, but can't add header (-H) to it

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
form.setAttribute("action", URL);
form.setAttribute("target", "_self");

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "amount");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "1000");
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
....
....
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

The problem is that to send header for it (token)

Comment: `form.submit` cannot add header. You need to submit this using javascript. Axios is pretty popular. https://axios-http.com/

Answer (score 0):

you need to use AJAX request with headers using the fetch API, setting the appropriate headers for `accept`, `token`, and `Content-Type`.

```
const url = 'URL';
const token = 'TOKEN VALUE';
const data = { 
  amount: 1000, 
  expireInSeconds: 0, 
  factorNumber: 'string', 
  redirectUrl: 'string' 
};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'token': token,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```